# Sum of Discrete Uniforms, but each value can be picked no more than N times?

Tags: uniform-distribution, discrete-data, sum

Suppose there are i.i.d. variables $X_{1,..n}$ with discrete uniform distribution with the support $[1, n]$. What would be the distribution of such a sum if we introduce the condition that each value cannot appear more than $N$ times in the sum?

E.g., if $N = 1$, we have sampling without replacement, if $N = 2$, any number can only appear twice in the sum. $N = \infty$ is equivalent to sampling with replacement.

Comment: Re "it is known:" that is incorrect.  The [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution#Definition) is that of a sum of *continuous* uniform variates supported on the interval $[0,1]=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid 0\le x \le 1\}.$  What, then, is your question: is it about discrete uniform variables or *continuous* ones?

Comment: Yes, I apologise about the Irwin-Hall comment

Comment: When $N=1$ there is only one sum possible, right?  Each number has to be selected once.  When $N\gt 3$ the result will be practically indistinguishable from the situation with $N=\infty$ (where the usual Normal approximation works very well).  The only noticeable departures are for $N=2$ and, with largish $n,$ for $N=3.$

Comment: Not sure "i.i.d" belongs there if the value of one realization affects subsequent realizations?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have $n$ possible observations (integers from 1 to $n$) from which you want to pick $k$ and sum those? The sum will depend on how many variables you select from your universe of possibilities. I must be missing something.

Comment: @Avraham A literal reading of the question is helpful.  It says that if we condition a bootstrap sample of the integers $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ on the largest number $N$ of replicates, what will be the distribution of the sum?

Comment: @whuber So to take case where $N = 2$, is the case that one selects $k$ numbers in $[1,\ldots,n]$ so long as no one number appears more than twice, where $k = n$ because it is a bootstrap? So the answer to $N = 1$ is simply $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: @Avraham Yes, that's what the question appears to ask, if we take it literally as written.

Answer (score 2):

Using the interpretation of @whuber in the comments, while I do not know if there is a closed form solution for this problem, it does lend itself to exploration via simulation. First, the answer for $N = 1$ is clear: it is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

For the remainder, I will use the assumption that *before* the bootstrap, every number is equiprobable. Once a number is chosen, well, it can only be chosen $N - 1$ more times. Therefore, the key will be for each investigation of $k\in 1,\ldots,n$ to generate $N$ versions of it first and then take a sample of size $n$ **without** replacement.

I think the code below should be straightforward:

```r
LimitedBoot <- function(n, N) {
  universe <- rep(1:n, each = N)
  sum(sample(universe, n, replace = FALSE))
}

GenSamps <- function(n, N, s) {
  if (n < 1 | N < 1) {stop('n and N must be >= 1')}
  n <- as.integer(n)
  N <- as.integer(N)
  s <- as.integer(s)
  # Create n/N pairs
  pars <- expand.grid(list(n = 1:n, N = 1:N))
  # Remove pairs which make no sense (repeats larger than support)
  pars <- pars[which(pars$N <= pars$n), ]
  # Pre-allocate your arrays if you can
  RS <- array(NA_integer_, # Just to be visually distinct from 0
              dim = c(max(pars$n), max(pars$N), s),
              dimnames = list(paste('n =', 1:max(pars$n)),
                          paste('N =', 1:max(pars$N)),
                              paste('samp', 1:s)))
  # Now for the loop. Traverse the par list and generate samples based on
  # restricted universe. Should result in a "triangular" array whose summary
  # functions will be a triangular matrix
  for (i in seq_along(pars$n)) {
    RS[pars$n[i], pars$N[i], ] <- replicate(s, LimitedBoot(pars$n[i], pars$N[i]))
  }
  RS
}
```

Now for some results:

```r
A <- GenSamps(20, 10, 1000))
apply(A, 1:2, mean)
       N = 1   N = 2   N = 3   N = 4   N = 5   N = 6   N = 7   N = 8   N = 9  N = 10
n = 1      1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
n = 2      3   3.032      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
n = 3      6   6.034   6.031      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
n = 4     10   9.955  10.082  10.050      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
n = 5     15  15.047  14.982  15.079  14.735      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
n = 6     21  21.055  20.893  20.859  21.065  21.063      NA      NA      NA      NA
n = 7     28  27.895  28.007  27.733  28.061  28.000  27.994      NA      NA      NA
n = 8     36  35.742  36.064  35.935  35.799  35.800  36.013  35.943      NA      NA
n = 9     45  44.703  45.239  45.101  45.406  44.977  44.547  44.677  45.141      NA
n = 10    55  55.288  54.671  55.283  55.206  54.817  55.289  55.663  55.377  55.016
n = 11    66  66.089  65.743  65.988  65.795  66.120  65.821  65.891  66.316  66.025
n = 12    78  78.176  78.581  78.285  77.238  77.962  77.943  77.693  77.864  78.033
n = 13    91  90.982  90.900  91.240  90.886  91.140  90.898  90.836  91.049  90.885
n = 14   105 105.220 105.198 104.947 105.049 104.283 104.872 105.116 104.765 105.352
n = 15   120 119.728 119.812 119.307 120.534 119.271 120.240 119.619 120.364 119.284
n = 16   136 136.224 135.710 137.342 135.584 136.038 135.879 136.171 135.876 136.839
n = 17   153 153.357 153.139 152.292 151.553 153.224 153.506 153.024 152.057 152.043
n = 18   171 169.771 171.534 170.605 170.935 172.119 172.505 171.139 171.510 170.463
n = 19   190 190.536 190.156 190.853 190.432 190.460 190.182 190.343 190.456 188.425
n = 20   210 210.424 209.707 208.926 209.473 209.296 211.183 210.185 211.365 209.907

print(apply(A, 1:2, sd), digits = 4L)
       N = 1   N = 2  N = 3  N = 4  N = 5  N = 6  N = 7  N = 8  N = 9 N = 10
n = 1      0      NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
n = 2      0  0.5756     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
n = 3      0  1.0927  1.227     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
n = 4      0  1.6958  1.901  1.956     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
n = 5      0  2.3406  2.638  2.800  2.828     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
n = 6      0  3.0324  3.454  3.794  3.858  3.911     NA     NA     NA     NA
n = 7      0  3.9719  4.370  4.598  4.900  4.866  4.985     NA     NA     NA
n = 8      0  4.7640  5.466  5.828  5.795  6.044  6.064  6.042     NA     NA
n = 9      0  5.5755  6.424  6.700  6.938  7.154  7.065  7.373  7.118     NA
n = 10     0  6.6798  7.609  8.060  8.259  8.368  8.386  8.538  8.689  9.109
n = 11     0  7.9423  8.642  9.076  9.522  9.754  9.991 10.219  9.703  9.827
n = 12     0  8.9740  9.836 10.367 10.844 11.110 11.289 11.351 11.374 11.144
n = 13     0  9.8402 11.400 11.793 11.596 12.704 12.656 12.015 12.776 12.578
n = 14     0 10.7711 11.905 13.131 13.523 13.471 14.177 13.836 14.799 14.528
n = 15     0 12.3837 13.228 14.660 15.334 15.463 15.535 16.723 15.910 15.976
n = 16     0 13.5296 15.390 15.746 16.439 16.882 17.241 17.538 17.652 17.032
n = 17     0 14.4006 16.711 17.840 18.325 18.491 18.915 18.278 18.901 18.588
n = 18     0 15.6137 18.004 19.633 20.110 20.455 19.992 20.567 20.794 20.972
n = 19     0 17.2709 18.816 21.074 21.038 22.452 21.958 22.613 22.216 22.756
n = 20     0 18.2661 21.367 22.371 22.566 23.614 23.260 23.534 23.628 24.504
```

The $N = 1$ columnn is what we expected. However. what is surprising is that the means of the remaining columns still cluster around $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. So either there is something wrong with my implementation or there may be some deeper symmetry involved.

#### Update with KDE plot for $N = 2$

Based on the comments below, the following sequence of plots may be of interest. Very lumpy when there are few options as most KDE plots of discrete distributions tend to be, but smooths into a nice Gaussian form pretty quickly.

[image]

Comment: There is a simple symmetry induced by replacing each number $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by $n+1-i.$  This interchanges any sum of $s$ with a (necessarily equally probable) sum of $n(n+1)-s,$ whose fixed point is $n(n+1)/2,$ while respecting the condition on $N.$

Comment: Zounds! As for the distribution itself, the ones I've spot checked looked rather Gaussian, but I haven't plotted all 155 density estimates.

Comment: Even for $n$ as small as $4,$ provided $N\ge 3$ you will see a *very* good approximation to a Gaussian distribution.  The only distributions of any interest (from this perspective) occur for $N=2.$  This is understandable, because the count of replications of any given value has nearly a Poisson$(1)$ distribution, which rarely exceeds $3,$ so conditioning on any $N\ge 3$ doesn't depart appreciably from simple random sampling (with replacement).

Answer (score 0):

Let $n = 20, N = 10.$ then the population from which we can sample (without replacement)
consists of $N$ copies of $1, 2, \dots, n.$ Then the maximum sample size is $200$ and a sample `x` of size $200$ will exactly match the population. Using R:

```
pop = rep(1:20, N)
summary(pop);  length(pop);  sd(pop)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    5.75   10.50   10.50   15.25   20.00 
[1] 200       # population size
[1] 5.780751  # population SD (with denom 199)

x = sample(pop, 200)
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    5.75   10.50   10.50   15.25   20.00 
[1] 200       # sample size
[1] 5.780751  # sample SD
```

That part is trivial. So your question must have something to
do with samples of size less than 200.  However, you give no
clue what that question is.

Let's look at a sample of size $50.$

```
set.seed(2021)
y = sample(pop, 50)
summary(y);  length(y);  sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    7.00   11.50   10.92   15.00   20.00 
[1] 50
[1] 5.382663
table(y)
y
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
  2  2  2  1  1  3  3  5  2  2  2  4  3  4  3  3  2  1  2  3
```

Comment: I believe "$n$" and "$N$" are intended to represent different quantities.  In effect, this is one of those nasty multinomial distribution questions having no simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get a reasonable normal distribution approximation with the following code. It is a bit heuristic and I have not yet a strong argument for this method. Below is the reasoning behind it:

I compute the variance by considering the sum as a sort of random walk process of the partial sum $S_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k} X_k$. With this random walk there is an attractive force towards $(n+1)/2$ because the mean of the variables that are not yet chosen will be higher/lower depending on the sum $S_k$. So if $S_k/k$ is larger/lower than $(n+1)/2$ then the expectation of $X_{k+1}$ will be the opposite and with a relative magnitude $\frac{k}{Nn-k}$.

This makes that the variance of $S_k$ is not simply $k \sigma^2$ with $\sigma^2 = \frac{n^2-1}{12}$ the variance of the discrete uniform distributed numbers from which the sample is taken. Instead, we *approximate* it with:

$$\text{Var}(S_{k+1}) = \frac{1}{(Nn-k)^2} \text{Var}(S_{k}) + \sigma^2$$

[image: histogram with normal estimate]

```
### function to simulate sampling with limited numbers
### and return the sum of the sample 
smp = function(n,N) {
  x = rep(1:n, times=N)
  y = sample(x,n,replace = 0)
  return(sum(y))
}


n = 30 ### size of population to sample 
nr = 10^6 ### number of simulation

### compute ranges for plotting
summu = n*(n+1)/2
sumvar = mean((c(1:n)-(n+1)/2)^2)*n

x_lims = summu + c(-3,3)*sumvar^0.5
y_lim = dnorm(summu, summu, sumvar^0.5)*2

plot(-100,-100, 
     xlim = x_lims, ylim = c(0,y_lim), 
     xlab = "sum", ylab = "frequency")


### compute for different values of N
for (i in 1:4) {
  N = c(2,3,4,n)[i]
  col = c(2,3,4,1)[i]
  
  #### repeat sampling and plotting
  z = replicate(nr,smp(n,N))
  h = hist(z, breaks = seq(-0.5,max(z+0.5),1), plot=0)
  points(h$mids, h$counts/nr, col=col, pch=21, bg=col, cex=0.5)

  ### normal approximation estimate
  mu = n*(n+1)/2
  ### compute variance 
  vr1 = mean((c(1:n)-(n+1)/2)^2)
  vr = vr1
  for (j in 1:(n-1)) {
    vr = vr * (1-1/(N*n-j))^2 + vr1
  }

  ### add line for normal approximation
  x = seq(min(x_lims),max(x_lims),0.1)
  lines(x,dnorm(x,mu,vr^0.5), col = col)
}

title("simulation and estimate for n = 30")   
legend(min(x_lims),y_lim, c("N = 2", "N = 3", "N = 4", "N = n"),
       col = c(2,3,4,1), pch = rep(21,4), lty = rep(1,4), pt.bg = c(2,3,4,1))
```